# AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'cupyx'

Tags: python, cupy

I have this python code when I run it ,it say

> AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'cupyx'

code:

```
# upload matrix and inverse diagonal GPU
A = cp.cupyx.scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(A)
```

I've installed cupy successfully in docker using

```
pip install cupy-cuda100
```

any help will be appreciated, thx

Comment: just before the call try doing `print dir(cp)`. Does the list contain the string `'cupyx'`? Do you use a variable called `cp` somewhere before this call?

Comment: when I print(dir(cp)),result is "..'__version__', '_cupy', '_cupyx', '_default_memory_pool',..", 'cupyx' isn't in the list . yes I called  cupy before ,there's no problem !

Answer (score 4):

See the discussion in https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/2654 and try the following

```
import cupyx.scipy.sparse
cupyx.scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(A)
```

The alias `cupy.cupyx` was unintentionally there in some prereleases, but it has been removed because it is too confusing.